# How to extract PortNumber from socket?

Tags: sockets, haskell

I am trying to extract Port Number from socket using this code

```
import           Network.Socket

let hints = defaultHints { addrSocketType = Stream }
addr:_ <- getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just "127.0.0.1") (Just "3000")
sock <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
socketPort  sock
```

but `socketPort  sock` always return 0 , why it returns 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've skipped one step (binding socket to an address):

```
bind sock (addrAddress addr)
```

Unbound socket returns `0.0.0.0:0`, that's why you always receive `0` as a result of `socketPort sock`